# How can I change the font size of a fraction in an index?

Tags: math-mode, equations, text-manipulation

I have, as part of an equation, the object

```
a^{5} \left(\frac{b}{c}\right)^{\frac{2}{3}}
```

The problem is that the `2` and `3` are very small (compared to the `5`) and I would like all sub/superscripts to be the same size just as all body text is the same size. Is there a way of defining the font size inside the `equation` environment?

Comment: Have you tried dfrac in place of frac?

Comment: I suggest writing `^{2/3}` or stick to `\frac`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've managed to solve it by replacing `\frac` by `\tfrac`.

Answer (score 3):

Try `dfrac` instead of `frac`:

```
a^{5} \left(\dfrac{b}{c}\right)^{\dfrac{2}{3}}
```

You will need the `amsmath` package

Comment: But then the `2` and `3` are _larger_ than the `5`!

Comment: I did not realize that. TY.